# App Engine Logs Import to Big Query Log Format

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I am currently streaming my App Engine logs into Big Query using the built-in streamer from the Console. As far as I can tell, you aren't allowed to define any functions to process the data.

Are there any best practices for the actual log contents? Currently, I am simply printing stuff using context.Infof which can print fields and values for structs, and the raw text goes into the column protoPayload.line.logMessage

It sounds much better to print JSON data and then use the JSON functions? 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#jsonfunctions

Answer (score 2):

This feature is pretty new and so I don't think there are any best practices yet. If you don't mind changing your code, logging JSON in your app logs and then using BigQuery's JSON functions is a great option. If you want to process existing app logs, you can also use [REGEXP_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#regularexpressionfunctions) to parse free-form text.

One thing to note is that if you have multiple app logs per request, they will be stored in a repeated field, and querying repeated fields in BigQuery is a little tricky. BigQuery will automatically flatten the results, so it might look like you have more request log entries than you have requests, if your query matches more than one app log per request. "GROUP BY protoPayload.requestId" can be useful in this case.